# PHP guzzlehttp returning different status code than curl

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I'm scraping a website for work so I can't give the url but when I curl the page I get 400 response. The same is true when I go to the page on chrome.

```
$ curl -I <url>
```

`HTTP/2 400
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
accept-ranges: bytes
accept-ranges: bytes
via: 1.1 varnish
age: 0
accept-ranges: bytes
accept-ranges: bytes
date: Tue, 25 Sep 2018 19:34:37 GMT
via: 1.1 varnish
x-served-by: cache-mdw17368-MDW, cache-bos8235-BOS
x-cache: MISS, MISS
x-cache-hits: 0, 0
x-timer: S1537904078.900892,VS0,VE33`

When I curl the same url with guzzleHttp it returns a 200 response code.

```
    try {
        $client->request('GET', $url, [
            'allow_redirects' => [
                'track_redirects' => true
            ]
        ]);
    } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
        return false;
    }
```

This is making it really hard for me to decipher which pages are relevant and which aren't is there a option that needs to be set?

Comment: Your curl seems to be configured to use HTTP 2.0, which might be part of the problem.

Comment: most likely you'll find the problem if you redirect both requests to http://dumpinput.ratma.net and compare the responses